# Erro in the passing id in the filter method using usereducer hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

The below code is facing an issue with deleting the list. Let me know what is the problem I have done. The issue in the case remove section in filter area. Passing id is the problem. Please simplify the issue.

function Reducerthree()

```
 {
    const inputRef = useRef();
    const initialstate = [{
        id: uuid(),
        country: "india"
    }]
            const [items, dispatch] = useReducer((state, action) => {
                switch (action.type) {
                    case'add':
                    return [
                        ...state, 
                        {
                            id: uuid(),
                            country: action.name
                        }
                    ];
                    case 'remove':
                        return state.filter(s => s.id !== action.id);
                    default: 
                    return state;
                }
            }, initialstate);


            function handleSubmit(event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                dispatch({
                    type: 'add',
                    name: inputRef.current.value
                });
                inputRef.current.value = '';
            }
    return (
        <div>
          <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
              <input ref={inputRef} />
                           </form>  
        <ul>
            {items.map((item, index) => (
                <li key={item.id}>{item.country}
                <button onClick={() => dispatch({type:'remove', index})}>close</button>
                </li>
            ))}
        </ul>

        </div>
    )
}

export default Reducerthree
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass `id` in action, you are not passing it. Change the remove action to be something like:

```
 <button onClick={() => dispatch({type:'remove', id: item.id})}>close</button>
```

Comment: What is the error ? Also do pass `item.id` not `index`

Comment: Wokring Now. Thanks!